# Amazon S3 iOS SDK v2 Upload with AWSAccessKeyId:Signature

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload file on S3 bucket and device is getting access information from another server (AWSAccessKeyId and Signature). Is it possible to upload file with AWS iOS SDK v2? If not are there any chances to use another approach possible for iOS (eg. generate Pre-Signed URL and do the http post/put)?

Right now I'm using this approach, but it's for access_key/access_secret:

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:awsAccessKey secretKey:awsSecretKey];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

AWSS3 *transferManager = [[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
AWSS3PutObjectRequest *getLog = [[AWSS3PutObjectRequest alloc] init];
getLog.bucket = awsS3Bucket;
getLog.key = awsS3FileNameString;
getLog.contentType = @"text/plain";
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:logFileName];
long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fileName error:nil][NSFileSize] longLongValue];
getLog.body = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];
getLog.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:fileSize];

[[transferManager putObject:getLog] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {        
    if(task.error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",task.error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Got here: %@", task.result);

    }
    return nil;
}];
```

I'll be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the following approach:

- Generate the **access key**, **secret key**, and **session token** on your server. You have many language options including Java, .NET, PHP, Ruby, Python, and Node.js.
- Implement your own credentials provider by conforming to [AWSCredentialsProvider](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v2/blob/master/AWSCore/Authentication/AWSCredentialsProvider.h#L37). This credentials provider should:

  - Retrieve the access key, secret key, and session key from your server.
  - Persist them until they expire.
  - Return the credentials when requested.
  - If they are expired, re-retrieve them from your server.
  - Calling `refresh` also should initiate the credentials retrieval process.
- Assign your credentials provider to `defaultServiceConfiguration` or pass it to `initWithConfiguration:`.

As a side note, when using `initWithConfiguration:`, you need to manually retain a strong reference to an instance of `AWSS3`. Using `defaultS3` will eliminate the need for this.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the side note. Unfortunately AWSCredentialsProvider doesn't support AWSAccessKeyId:Signature

Comment: We are now doing this by generating PUT to pre-signed URL generated on the server (I find this solution as easiest one IMO)

Comment: In order to generate a signature, you need temporary credentials. Instead of calculating the signature on the server, you can send out the temporary credentials to the device. The issues with the presigned URL approach are: 1) You cannot take advantage of multipart upload. 2) You have to handle retries for yourself. If they are acceptable downsides for your use case, presigned URL should work fine.